# Navigate up not working

Tags: android

I have three activities A->B->C. Sometimes I launch Activity C directly from A. Even then, when the user presses the "up" button, I want to go to activity B. So after a lot of searching, I am doing this:

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity
  android:name=".B"
  android:parentActivityName=".A"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
<activity
  android:name=".C"
  android:parentActivityName=".B"/>
```

In *Activity C*:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

....

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,upIntent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But when I start activity C from A, the up button just goes back to A, instead of creating a new instance of B. 
Even the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) state:

> When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: i think you clear all top activity that why this thing happen..remove this line `upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` and than run..i am not sure because code is not complete

Comment: Try changing to `Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);`, where `B` is the name of your activity B. Then call `startActivity(upIntent );` instead of `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,upIntent);`

Comment: Yes, that is working. But why is the above code not working? Is it not the intended behavior?